# In NGINX, is there a directive to limit the time it takes to establish new client connections?

Tags: nginx, configuration, http, timeout

In Nginx there's the [client_header_timeout](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_timeout) directive that sets a timeout for receiving the complete headers of an http request from a client. In the docs it is not specified if this timeout includes the connection opening/ssl handshake period. Perhaps there's another directive that controls it or client_header_timeout perhaps already includes it?

Comment: Curious as to the use-case here.

Comment: The process of TCP handshake is performed by the kernel and is not controlled by Nginx. It is handed to Nginx only when the connection is established (the 3-way handshake succeeded).

Comment: @symcbean The Slowloris ddos attack [can target the SSL handshake](https://www.powerwaf.com/learning/ddos-attacks/slowloris-attack/#the-types-and-variants-of-slowloris-attacks). One way to mitigate it is to set a strict timeout on SSL negotiations and handshakes. In addition, one of the major selling points of even deploying a proxy server is to handle SSL Termination such that your app doesn't have to, and I think it's important to have better control over this process in general.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov The SSL handshake however is not and I think it's important to have fine control over SSL termination. Also, it's not entirely true that the user has no control over the tcp handshake: for example the [tcp_syn_retries](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) parameter exists and a few other interesting ones.

Comment: I was under the impression that client_header_timeout explicitly dealt with this case (e.g. https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2011/11/02/how-to-protect-against-slow-http-attacks) . Do you have reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: @symcbean I think the article you linked doesn't in any way imply that client_header_timeout includes the initial tcp handshake nor the ssl handshake...

Comment: I think SSL handshake is also out of control of Nginx as it is controlled by the OpenSSL library. But I didn't find any references on timeouts in the OpenSSL manuals (which are awful). Ok, the answer is: there is **no such directive in Nginx**.

Comment: Would it be so hard to test?